# why if statement doesn't work?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this php code:

```
$flag = 0;
$f = fopen("1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($f))
{
    $a = fgets($f);
    $b = explode(",", $a);
    if ($_POST['username'] == $b[0]&& $_POST['password'] == $b[1])
    {
        $flag = 1;
        echo ("Correct");
        break;
    }
}
 if ($flag == 0)
     echo ("Incorrect");
fclose($f);
```

and `1.txt` file is this:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
```

I send data to my php page that have **just** this code but I always get `Incorrect`. I don't know why if doesn't work!(I checked the `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` but all were correct!) can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually doing a POST and not a GET?  Perhaps use $_REQUEST instead?

Comment: @Marvo: yes. the method is `POST`. I also checked the content of posts and they were correct!

Comment: Also: investigate fgetcsv, or file_get_contents and str_getcsv. Your issue are the trailing newlines from the file.

Comment: When in doubt, `var_dump($_POST)` (*and `var_dump` anything else relevant*)

Comment: @Bracketworks: Also `var_dump($a)` :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to `trim($b[1])` because it probably reads the new line into the string so `$b[1]` would never be equal.

**Edit:**

Actually, you should just replace `$a = fgets($f);` with `$a = trim(fgets($f));`

Answer (score 1):

Simple echo `b[0]`, `b[1]`, `$_POST['username']`, and `$_POST['password']`

I have a feeling one of these values won't be what you expect, which will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
$flag = 0;
$f = fopen("1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($f))
{
    $a = fgets($f);
    $a = trim($a);
    $b = explode(",", $a);
    var_dump($b);
    if ($_POST['username'] == $b[0] && $_POST['password'] == $b[1])
    {
        $flag = 1;
        echo ("Correct");
        break;
    }
}
if ($flag == 0)
    echo ("Incorrect");
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I would do it, using [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

```
<?php 
//Get file
$file = file('1.txt');

//Split the array line in two with delimiter ,
function split_it(&$value){
        $value = explode(',',$value);
}
array_walk($file,'split_it');

//Check values passed against the array, and return true or false
function check_it($file,$a,$b){
    foreach($file as $row){
        if(trim($row[0])==trim($a) && trim($row[1])==trim($b)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


//The business part
$a = (isset($_POST['a'])?$_POST['a']:null);
$b = (isset($_POST['b'])?$_POST['b']:null);

if(check_it($file,$a,$b)==true){
    echo 'Correct';
}else{
    echo 'In-correct';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Separate $b[0] from && to make if statement work.

```
 if ($_POST['username'] == $b[0] && $_POST['password'] == $b[1])
    {
        $flag = 1;
        echo ("Correct");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The only time this might be an issue is if following the ampersand there is a variable and no space. It might confuse the interpreter considering reference notation; `&$foo`